# Range search within specified radius in an Octree

Tags: octree

I am interested in particle algorithms like the N-Body, and SPH. One of the important steps in these applications is, given a query point,  to find the particles
lying within a specified sphere of radius 'h'.

Now I have heard that Octrees are good spatial data structures for problems like N-body or SPH.

But after the octree construction,  I cannot understand how the "locate particles within a radius" step is performed .  Can someone please point me to some references, papers or articles for doing this step?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[k-d trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) are also good data structures to use for this and are commonly used for nearest neighbor searches.

Comment: Yes kd trees seem to be a very nice data structure for range searching. Thank you! :D

Comment: Downvoted because you didn't answer the OP's question

Answer (score 2):

Guessing that Octree contains 3dPoint objects:
"locate particles within a radius 3 of Point p" can be expressed as 
"Return all points contained in Octreecells touching or intersecting with Sphere(center p, radius r)"
To test if a cell intersects a sphere:

```
dx,dy,dz = 0;
if (pX < minX of Cell)
    dx = |px - minX|
else if (px > maxX of Cell)
    dx = |px-maxX|
Same for other dimensions

return (|dx,dy,dz|<=r)
```